# Conditional/max mongo queries using spring mongoTemplate

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mongodb, mongotemplate

I have hundreds of records like these in a mongodb collection:

```
{
    "city" : "London",
    "eventTime": 1582866000,
    "createdTime": 1582900145,
    "eventDetails: {
        ...
    }
}
```

This is corresponding the `Event` class

```
public class Event {
    private String city;
    private long eventTime;
    private long createdTime;
    private EventDetails eventDetails;

    //getters and setters
}
```

-`eventTime` (all time values are in local epoch/unix time) will always be equal to an hour
-`createdTime` is being used as version control (greater the `createdTime`, more recent the version of this information)
- not using update/upsert as I have uses for keeping older information
I want to be able to query something like this:
1) given a version timestamp - return a list of objects (the entire object) for each `city`, for each `eventTime`, where timestamp is closest to (floor or celing) `createdTime`
2) same as 1) but for max(createdTime) - for each `city` and every `eventTime`

Essentially - there will be a lot of duplicates for each `city`, for each `eventTime` due to multiple versions, and I only want the version that I specify, and the latest version

I'm trying to do these two queries using mongoTemplate in java (spring mongo)
I've tried messing around with `Query`, `Aggregation`, `AggregationOperator.Max`
but nothing seems to be working

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("city").is(city)),
Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("eventTime").gte(startTime).lte(endTime)),
Aggregation.group("$$ROOT").max("createdTime").as("createdTime")
);
AggregationResults<Event> groupResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "collection-name", Event.class);
result = groupResults.getMappedResults();
```

sample data and expected outputs: https://script.google.com/d/1JgOFzdVBGiueYpXT8u-R6AJpbX6FxxtkVwq_NpLraZeS19Pxh6zmnATb/edit?usp=sharing

I have also tried doing these queries in mongodb shell and haven't been successful with that either, it's similar but it's not returning the object structure that I want

```
db.getCollection('collection-name').aggregate([{$group:{_id : "$$ROOT", createdTime : {$max:"$createdTime"}}}])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Max

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        city: "$city",
        eventTime: "$eventTime"
      },
      max: {
        $max: "$createdTime"
      },
      data: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      max_events: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$data",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$max",
              "$$this.createdTime"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$max_events"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$max_events"
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xSxAPRxB6j9)

### MongoTemplate

```
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.*;

Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(
    group("city", "eventTime").max("createdTime").as("max").push("$$ROOT").as("data"),
    project().and(new AggregationExpression() {
        @Override
        public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
            return new Document("$filter",
                    new Document("input", "$data")
                         .append("cond", new Document("$eq", Arrays.asList("$max", "$$this.createdTime"))));
        }
    }).as("max_events"),
    unwind("max_events"),
    replaceRoot("max_events")
);

AggregationResults<Event> events = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(Event.class), Event.class);

for(Event ev: events) {
    System.out.println(ev);
}
```

### Closest

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        city: "$city",
        eventTime: "$eventTime"
      },
      data: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      closest: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$data",
          initialValue: {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              "$data",
              0
            ]
          },
          in: {
            $cond: [
              {
                $lt: [
                  {
                    $abs: {
                      $subtract: [
                        "$$this.eventTime",
                        "$$this.createdTime"
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    $abs: {
                      $subtract: [
                        "$$value.eventTime",
                        "$$value.createdTime"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
              "$$this",
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$closest"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$closest"
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4ia8qRRJD42)

### MongoTemplate

```
Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(
    group("city", "eventTime").push("$$ROOT").as("data"),
    project().and(new AggregationExpression() {
        @Override
        public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
            return new Document("$reduce",
                    new Document("input", "$data")
                     .append("initialValue", new Document("$arrayElemAt", Arrays.asList("$data", 0)))
                     .append("in", new Document("$cond", Arrays.asList(
                            new Document("$lt",  Arrays.asList(
                                new Document("$abs", new Document("$subtract", Arrays.asList("$$this.eventTime", "$$this.createdTime"))), 
                                new Document("$abs", new Document("$subtract", Arrays.asList("$$value.eventTime", "$$value.createdTime"))))), 
                            "$$this",
                            "$$value"))));
        }
    }).as("closest"),
    unwind("closest"),
    replaceRoot("closest")
);

AggregationResults<Event> events = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(Event.class), Event.class);

for(Event ev: events) {
    System.out.println(ev);
}
```

Comment: I got to run this query, and I think I messed up in my explanation. so each there is a one-to-many relationship between eventTime and createdTime, so each eventTime can have multiple createdTime, because createdTime is being used as a record-version. And I want to return a list of Event objects where for each eventTime in the range provided, it returns the max createdTime for it's corresponding eventTime and the closest createdTime for each corresponding eventTime

Comment: @Prady Post please sample data with expected result

Comment: here is a link with sample data, expected output for MAX and for CLOSEST in each file, I've added the link in the question

Comment: @Prady checking your samples

Comment: @Prady check if this solution meets your requirements https://mongoplayground.net/p/mnnOLV1ZOrf. We can split this query into 2 individual queries

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm looking for, thank you so much! Can we split this to two queries and find a way to do it through spring mongoTemplate? Also I tried running this on NoSQL Manager and it gave me a "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: 'replaceWith'"

Comment: You can change `$replaceWith` (since v4.2) to `$replaceRoot:{newRoot:"$max_events"}`

Comment: @Prady Ready. Try to execute these queries

Comment: works well, thank you very much. You've been incredibly helpful! I don't know how long it would've taken me to figure this out myself. Also, if I want to limit the `eventTime` range, do I just add a `Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("eventTime").gte(startTime).lte(endTime))` in your query?

Comment: @Prady yes. You may add several conditions to match criteria